# Проиграть два звука через один источник выхода openal

Tags: c++

Можно ли как-то проиграть два разных аудио файла одновременно с помощью openAL?

Comment: Лучше попробуйте "на лету" объединить эти два аудиофайла в один, если не найдете лучшего решения

Comment: Да, легко, просто создаете два отдельных source. Поясните, в чем конкретно сложность.